# Numeric Data Validation While Loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, validation, while-loop

I have a function usenum

```
function TF = usenum(x)

   TF = false;
   if ~isnumeric(x)
       h = msgbox('Input is not numeric');
   elseif (x <= 0)
       h = msgbox('Input must be > 0');
   else
       TF = true;
   end
```

I am getting user input in the main menu:

```
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
```

The inputdlg has 2 values and can be indexed by {1} and {2}

I want to wait for the user to input a value, the value has to be a number and greater than 0. in the case that he doesn't, I want to output the respective message and make him keep inputting until he gets it right, or close the inputdlg dialog.

I am attempting something like this:

```
condition = false;
while ~condition
    answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
    numOfTracks = answer{1};
    bpmRange = answer{2};
    condition = usenum(numOfTracks);
end
```

I am trying to say, while condition = false, i.e. while input is not numeric or not greater than 0, keep getting user input. Once the user inputs a valid number the condition is supposed to become true and the while is supposed to terminate. However, the inputdlg keeps opening for input and the only way I can stop it is by closing it (infinite loop). how can I achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you verify my answer and get back to me? If it's not correct, please post some sample values of `numOfTracks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop appears to be correct. The following testing provides results of your `usenum` function.

```
>> usenum('')
ans =
     0
>> usenum(-1)
ans =
     0
>> usenum(1)
ans =
     1
```

Your `usenum` function is correct as far as typing is concerned, but I believe your input is always given as a string since you're getting user input from a dialogue. Instead, you should try redefine `usenum` as follows if you're expecting a string input. The function `str2double` converts it to a double and if it's text, it will show as `NaN`. That's what the `isnan` check is for, to check if it's text.

```
function TF = usenum(x)
    % Default to false
    TF = false;
    x = str2double(x);
    % Check if digits
    if isnan( x )
        h = msgbox('Input is not numeric');
    elseif (x <= 0)
        h = msgbox('Input must be > 0');
    else
        TF = true;
    end
```

This is the result of the new function.

```
>> usenum('a')
ans =
     0
>> usenum('-1')
ans =
     0
>> usenum('1')
ans =
     1
```

Comment: Thanks very much! but how exactly does a detail like this even come to mind? sometimes these things make me go crazy!

Comment: Experience, many failures, and many hours of debugging :) we all make the same mistake when we begin

Comment: thanks again. how do you suggest I could handle the case of the user cancelling the input dlg (in the while loop)?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with `inputdlg` specifically before. Does `inputdlg` return something to differentiate if the dialogue is cancelled? What's the value of `answer` in that case?

Comment: Fixed. I break the loop if 'answer' is empty meaning the user cancelled, and set numOfTracks if not (which means the user entered something).

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri Perfect, I thought something there would indicate a "cancel" :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75889/discussion-between-jurgen-cuschieri-and-krisdestruction).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75892/discussion-between-jurgen-cuschieri-and-krisdestruction).

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri I see you tried to contact me. Personally I hate the chat system because it forces you to chat in realtime. Let's continue it here. Actually after thinking about it, if you want to minimize code, you should probably keep the msgbox in the function and use this code within your loop http://pastebin.com/Lqn0b1HL